# Pan not working after resizing contentView in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`'s:

[image: cell]

Whenever I pan on `self.view`, the table won't pan. It only works when I'm panning on `contentView`.

How can I make the table pan even if I pan on `self.view` with this construction?

In the tableView it shows it's registering a touch in `touchesShouldBegin(:with:in)`.

However when the pan is starting from `self.view`, no gestures will be registered in the cell's `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(:)`

Comment: you can make `contentView` size equal to `self.view` size, its `backgroundColor = .clear` and add `UIView` inside `contentView` with size you want.

Comment: Unfortunately the subclass is quite complicated and would like it if I don't have to change the `frame` of `contentView`.

Comment: You should always attach your gesture recognizers to the table view itself—not to a specific cell or view. The UITableView class is a descendant of UIScrollView, so attaching your gesture recognizers to the table view is less likely to interfere with the other gestures that must be tracked.

Comment: The "pan" of a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` I mentioned in the question is the standard gesture recognizer of the tableView itself. I didn't add a different gesture recognizer to the cell.